# Можно ли вычислить реальный ip если отправить email через TOR

Tags: tor

Можно ли вычислить реальный IP если отправить e-mail через ТОR?
Каким образом это делается? И были ли случаи, когда вычисляли?

Если известен только левый IP через него как-то можно?

Comment: Тут тысяча и одна ситуация может быть.

Comment: Зависит от способа отправки. В теле письма сервер или программа может указывать свой IP. Проверить можно только отправив письмо себе и тщательно все изучив.